# Finding probability for geometric random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> Let X is a Geometric random variable with parameter p. Let A be the event that X is a multiple of three. What is the value of P(A)?

I know that the answer to this is P(X=3) + P(X=6)... which becomes,

(1-p)^2 * p + (1-p)^5 * p ... and so on

But is there a way to express this answer without a never ending equation?

Comment: Any thoughts?  This looks like an entirely routine question about geometric series.

Comment: If you are intimidated by "never ending equations" I'm afraid you will not get very far in the study of probability...

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you so much for your valuable comment

Answer (score 2):

Hint: With $\mid r \mid < 1$ we have $a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots = \frac{a}{1-r}.$